# Type mismatch with pattern matching

Tags: f#

I have a code which works fine:

```
let rec calculate s l acc =
    if length s = 0 then
        acc
    else
        if first s = l then
            calculate (rest s) l (acc+1)
        else
            calculate (rest s) (first s) acc
```

I want to rewrite it using pattern matching:

```
let rec calculate s l acc =
    function
    | _, _, _ when length s = 0 -> acc
    | _, _, _ when first s = l  -> calculate (rest s) l (acc+1)
    | _, _, _                   -> calculate (rest s) (first s) acc
```

But last function returns the error message:

> ```
>   | _, _, _ when first s = l  -> calculate (rest s) l (acc+1)   -----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> /Users/demas/temporary/stdin(512,36): error FS0001: Type mismatch.
>   Expecting a
>       'a     but given a
>       'b * 'c * 'd -> 'a     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''b * 'c * 'd -> 'a'

Why ?

Comment: This is a case where pattern matching doesn't really bring anything though. I would just use your original code, with `elif` instead of `else if` to avoid too deep indentation, but that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keyword `function` implies that the last (implicit) parameter of the function `calculate` should  be tuple containing 3 elements because you are matching on _, _, _
You could rewrite it as:

```
let rec calculate s l acc =
    match s, l, acc with
    | _, _, _ when length s = 0 -> acc
    | _, _, _ when first s = l  -> calculate (rest s) l (acc+1)
    | _, _, _                   -> calculate (rest s) (first s) acc
```

Also you could make pattern matching more clear rewriting it like:

```
let rec calculate s l acc =
    match (length s), (first s = l) with
    | 0, _    -> acc
    | _, true -> calculate (rest s) l (acc+1)
    | _, _    -> calculate (rest s) (first s) acc
```

Comment: Thanks.  But why it repeat this correct line 'when first s = l  -> calculate (rest s) l (acc+1)' and not previous one  in the error message ?

Comment: It is because all branches of pattern matching should be of the same type. Compiler inferred that this type should be 'a (generic type of parameter 'acc') - type of the first branch because type inference happens from top to bottom. And this is why it gives the type error on the second branch.

Comment: Also I added the code of pattern matching that shorter and would have more sense

Comment: It is not equivalent code, as I see. If length of s will be zero, the 'first' function returns error. But yes, of course I can rewrite my 'first' function.